# Replace Random Access File Logics with FileOutput streams

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

My code currently use RandomAccessFile to read a ZIP file. The code is taken from a open source

project.
I need to make RANDOM Access File operation in memory without creating a physical File in

the disk. So need to replace functionality of RandomAccess File with FileOutput Stream.

The way Random Access File object Create.

```
protected RandomAccessFile file;

public ExtRandomAccessFile(File zipFile) throws IOException {
this.file = new RandomAccessFile(zipFile, "r");
}
```

Usage access different position mapped to the Random Access File

```
int censig = raFile.readInt( fileOffset );
short fileNameLength = raFile.readShort( fileOffset + 28 );
short extraFieldLength = raFile.readShort( fileOffset + 30 );
long fileOffsetPos = fileOffset + 28 + 14;
long fileDataOffset = raFile.readInt( fileOffsetPos );
int locsig = raFile.readInt( fileDataOffset );
```

Please advice me how do I replace my code with FileOutputstream. What is the

mechanism I should use to look up for values.

Thanks

Comment: Just use the java.util.zip package. It's documented.

Comment: I am using ZIP But this is a password protected ZIP file which java standard package does not support

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) to read different values. But be careful, because java always uses big endian format. If you don't do this for educational reasons, I would recommend [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) to create zip files.

Comment: ZIPOutputStream is not a option as my ZIP is password protected.

Comment: Will try DataOutputStream